# QGIS: Placing points relative to a specific coordinate

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, utm, point-cloud

I have some delimited-text point data that is encoded as X,Y positions relative to a given coordinate. So, for example, `1 5` represents a point 1 meter east, five meters north of the origin coordinate. It is essentially a UTM projection but does not use a standard zone. What is the best way to import this data into QGIS?

Comment: Yes, you can figure out some sort of process in QGIS involving custom projections, or PyQGIS scripting.  It involves a bit of research and thinking.  But if it is only one file, you can just open it in Excel, apply a quick formula to convert to the coordinate of the origin point, and then open in QGIS - with little research or thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a UTM-like projection that isn't a standard UTM zone, you can just specify your own Transverse Mercator coordinate system.

Here's the PROJ.4 page on [Transverse Mercator](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/tmerc.html#tmerc) projections.

If your grid origin is known in geographic Longitude, Latitude coordinates, your projection will look like:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=ORIGIN_LAT +lon_0=ORIGIN_LON +k_0=1 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

To create a custom projection in QGIS, go to `Settings > Custom Projections... > [+] sign` and then give it a name and supply the projection definition from above.

Then to load a CSV, go to `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer` and click the globe button next to Geometry CRS. Search for your custom projection, then confirm until your data is added to the map.

Comment: Adjust the false easting and northing by your *known coordinate* and this homebrew CRS becomes a *local datum*, used often in mine sites and by users of CAD software... because it keeps the coordinate values small (for example instead of 512341, 7123455 using a local datum becomes 1,5 - less chance of misreading).

Comment: I used the rule you suggested and it seemed to work, except that my point cloud is significantly offset from where it ought to be. [This](https://proj4.org/faq.html#changing-ellipsoid-why-can-t-i-convert-from-wgs84-to-google-earth-virtual-globe-mercator) section of the FAQ seems to be relevant to what's happening, but adding `+nadgrids=@null` to my specification does not solve the problem. I think perhaps `+ellps=WGS84` is not the ideal ellipsoid but I don't know what option would be better. The area I'm working on is in Norway, so it's pretty far north, if that helps.

Comment: Here is an image of the point cloud overlaid with other (correct) chart shapes: https://imgur.com/a/wEH4y8h

Comment: @JohnAllie It indeed does like a datum/ellipsoid difference. Maybe you can view the CRS information for your polygon file and see what datum/ellipsoid it is in.